Efficient Group Transportation in a One-Street City: Balancing Gender Requirements and Cost
Task:
In the city of San Fierro, all buildings lie along a single street. You are Carl, the only taxi driver, tasked with transporting a group of n boys and m girls from a club at the street's beginning to their homes, which are further down the street. The taxi can hold up to 4 passengers, and you will drop off passengers based on their distances, charging 1 CU per kilometer. Each taxi must include at least one boy, but he doesn't need to be the last one dropped off.
Input Format:

The first line contains n (1 ≤ n ≤ 2011) — the number of boys. The next n lines provide each boy's name and distance from the club.
Following this, the number m is given, followed by m lines with each girl's name and distance.
Names consist of letters with the first letter uppercase; lengths are 1 to 15 characters. Distances are non-negative integers not exceeding 10,000.

Task is to determine how to split the group into taxis to minimize total transport costs.
My problem:
This task is for dynamic programming, but I tried to solve it without using this approach and get an error on one of the tests. I would be very grateful if someone would point out an error in my algorithm, suggest a test that my program does not pass correctly, or offer their own solution to this problem.
Steps Taken:

Sorting:

I sorted all individuals in descending order of distance from the club. This allows the taxi to drop off passengers in the order of their homes, minimizing the overall distance traveled.


Taxi Allocation:

I iterated through the sorted list, filling each taxi with up to four passengers. A flag was used to track if at least one boy was included.


Ensuring a Boy in Each Taxi:

If a taxi was filled without any boys, I checked the remaining unallocated passengers for a boy. If none were found, I used a helper function to swap out one of the girls in the current taxi with a boy from a previously filled taxi, ensuring compliance with the requirement.


Cost Calculation:

For each taxi, I calculated the maximum distance of the passengers, as the fare is based on the furthest drop-off point.



Here is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string name;
    int distance;
    bool isBoy;
};

// Comparator to sort persons by distance in descending order
bool compareByDistance(const Person &a, const Person &b) {
    return a.distance > b.distance;
}

// Helper function to find the index of the girl with the minimum distance in the taxi
int findMinDistanceGirlIndex(const vector<Person> &taxi) {
    int minDistance = 1e9, minIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < taxi.size(); ++i) {
        if (!taxi[i].isBoy && taxi[i].distance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = taxi[i].distance;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}

// Helper function to find the index of the girl with the maximum distance in the taxi
int findMaxDistanceGirlIndex(const vector<Person> &taxi) {
    int maxDistance = -1e9, maxIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < taxi.size(); ++i) {
        if (!taxi[i].isBoy && taxi[i].distance > maxDistance) {
            maxDistance = taxi[i].distance;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

// Helper function to find the index of the boy with the minimum distance in a taxi
int findMinDistanceBoyIndex(const vector<Person> &taxi) {
    int minDistance = 1e9, minIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < taxi.size(); ++i) {
        if (taxi[i].isBoy && taxi[i].distance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = taxi[i].distance;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}

// Recursive function to pull a boy from previous taxis if necessary
void ensureBoyInPreviousTaxis(vector<vector<Person>> &taxis, vector<Person> &currentTaxi, int taxiIndex) {
    if (taxiIndex < 0) return;  // Base case: no more taxis to go back to
    
    vector<Person> &previousTaxi = taxis[taxiIndex];
    int minBoyIndex = findMinDistanceBoyIndex(previousTaxi);
    int maxGirlIndex = findMaxDistanceGirlIndex(currentTaxi);

    // Swap the girl out with the boy from the previous taxi
    swap(currentTaxi[maxGirlIndex], previousTaxi[minBoyIndex]);

    // Check if the previous taxi still has a boy after the swap
    if (findMinDistanceBoyIndex(previousTaxi) == -1) {
        ensureBoyInPreviousTaxis(taxis, currentTaxi, taxiIndex - 1);
    }
}

// Function to display the contents of all taxis
void displayTaxis(const vector<vector<Person>> &taxis) {
    for (int i = 0; i < taxis.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "Taxi " << i + 1 << ":";
        for (size_t j = 0; j < taxis[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << (j > 0 ? (j == taxis[i].size() - 1 ? " and " : ", ") : " ") << taxis[i][j].name;
        }
        cout << "." << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    int n, m;

    // Reading number of boys
    cin >> n;
    vector<Person> people;

    // Reading boys' information
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Person boy;
        cin >> boy.name >> boy.distance;
        boy.isBoy = true;
        people.push_back(boy);
    }

    // Reading number of girls
    cin >> m;

    // Reading girls' information
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        Person girl;
        cin >> girl.name >> girl.distance;
        girl.isBoy = false;
        people.push_back(girl);
    }

    // Sort all people by distance in descending order
    sort(people.begin(), people.end(), compareByDistance);

    vector<vector<Person>> taxis; // List of all taxis

    int i = 0;

    // Process until all people are taken home
    while (i < people.size()) {
        vector<Person> taxi;
        bool hasBoy = false;

        // Add first 4 people from the sorted list to the taxi
        for (int j = 0; j < 4 && i < people.size(); ++j) {
            taxi.push_back(people[i]);
            if (people[i].isBoy) {
                hasBoy = true;
            }
            ++i;
        }

        // If there is no boy in the current taxi, try to find one
        if (!hasBoy) {
            bool boyFound = false;

            // Look for a boy in the unallocated list first
            for (int k = i; k < people.size(); ++k) {
                if (people[k].isBoy) {
                    int minGirlIndex = findMinDistanceGirlIndex(taxi);
                    people.insert(people.begin(), taxi[minGirlIndex]);  // Add the girl back to the beginning of the list
                    taxi[minGirlIndex] = people[k];                      // Replace her with the boy
                    people.erase(people.begin() + k);                   // Remove the boy from the list
                    boyFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If no boys left in the unallocated list, pull one from previous taxis
            if (!boyFound) {
                ensureBoyInPreviousTaxis(taxis, taxi, taxis.size() - 1);
            }
        }

        // Add this taxi to the list of taxis
        taxis.push_back(taxi);
    }

    // Calculate total cost at the end based on the maximum distance for each taxi
    int totalCost = 0;
    for (const auto &taxi : taxis) {
        int maxDistance = -1; // Initialize to a very small value
        for (const auto &person : taxi) {
            maxDistance = max(maxDistance, person.distance);
        }
        totalCost += maxDistance;
    }

    // Output the total cost and number of trips
    cout << totalCost << endl;
    cout << taxis.size() << endl;

    // Display the contents of all taxis
    displayTaxis(taxis);

    return 0;
}

Test
Input:
2
Mark 5
Alex 10
5
Anna 1
Maria 12
Carol 10
Elena 8
Lisa 6

Output:
18
2
Taxi 1: Mark, Lisa and Anna.
Taxi 2: Alex, Maria, Carol and Elena.


The least I can say is that your question is not clear. Carl's the only taxi driver but there are many taxis? And more prosaically, I don't see an easy way to understand what is going on without some debugging information, incl. an input and corresponding expected/incorrect actual output.

@Atmo About Karl, this is the legend of the author of the task, I agree, it is not very correctly formulated (meaning that he returns to the club after each trip, we can say that there are several taxis). As for the tests: that's the point, I don't understand why my algorithm might be wrong, and I was hoping that someone on StackOverflow would explain this to me or offer their solution to this problem. Also i write it in "My problem"

@Atmo there is obviously only one taxi, but multiple taxi rides. Otherwise, the question doesn't make sense.

@Atmo Yes, it is, I submit the solution to the testing system and do not know which test fails. This test is just an example of input and output. I was just hoping that someone using the solution algorithm would be able to come up with a counterexample.

To me you have more than 1 problems.... I built a test case with 4 boys, 10 girls, resulting in 4 taxis. So far so good ... except for the fact that taxi 1 only carries girls and taxi 3 has 2 boys... And I think the principle behind your algorithm is wrong too but I'm struggling proving it because of that first bug...

To reproduce: just make it so the sorted people vector has 5 consecutive people of the same sex (or 4 if at an end of the list), e.g. create a list with n boys all at distance 1 and m girls all at distance 5 with m >= 4. And I confirm that I think your algorithm will still be wrong after you correct that point.

@Atmo Yes, you are absolutely right, thank you! Now I will try to understand the reason)
